# Is it possible to point class instance variables to `inout` parameters in Swift?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Is it possible for multiple class methods to access and modify a single inout parameter that is set in the class constructor? For example something like this:

```
class X {
    var mySwitch: Bool
    
    init(mySwitch: inout Bool) {
        self.mySwitch = mySwitch
    }
    
    func updateSwitch() {
        self.mySwitch.toggle() // this should toggle the external Boolean value that was originally passed into the init
  }
}

// usage
var myBool: Bool = false
let x = X(mySwitch: &myBool)
x.updateSwitch()
print(myBool) // this should read 'true'
```

Comment: Mutating captures to value types like this are explicitly forbidden, specifically to prevent this. Allowing that would make them into shared mutable state, which entirely defeats the purpose of value types.

Comment: Could you expand on `explicitly forbidden, specifically to prevent this`? Even though value types can have shared state (by explicitly passing them with & to an inout param) is there some advantage to limiting this to the scope of a single method?

Comment: `inout` acts as if the value was copied in at the time it was passed into the call, and copied out (overwriting the original) at the end of the call. There's not aliasing (multiple references to the same mutable state) happening, so it's acceptable.

Comment: Got it, thanks @Alexander.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Short Answer

No.

## Long Answer

There are other approaches that can satisfy this.

### Binding Variables

In SwiftUI we use Binding Variables to do stuff like this. When the Binding variable updates, it also updates the bound variable. I'm not sure if it will work in Sprite Kit.

```swift
class X {
    var mySwitch: Binding<Bool>

    init(_ someSwitch: Binding<Bool>) {
        self.mySwitch = someSwitch 
    }

   func toggle() { mySwitch.wrappedValue.toggle() }
}

struct Y {
    @State var mySwitch: Bool = false
    lazy var switchHandler = X($mySwitch)
}
```

### Callbacks

We can add a callback to `X` and call it on `didSet` of the boolean.

```swift
class X {
    var mySwitch: Bool {
        didSet { self.callback(mySwitch) } // hands the new value back to the call site in Y
    }

    let callback: (Bool) -> Void

    init(_ someSwitch: Bool, _ callback: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        self.mySwitch = someSwitch
        self.callback = callback
    }

    func toggle() { mySwitch = !mySwitch } // explicitly set to trigger didSet
}

class Y {
    var mySwitch: Bool = false
    lazy var switchHandler = X(mySwitch) {
        self.mySwitch = $0 // this is where we update the local value
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. I could always import SwiftUI into my SpriteKit files to leverage `Binding`, but I'm going to use the Callback pattern as it looks really straight-forward and opens the door to easily implementing additional functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: NO.

Your question does not make sense. An inout parameter allows you read/write access to the parameter during the call to function. It has no meaning once the function returns. You sem to think it creates some persistent link between the parameter that is passed as inout and some other variable. It DOES NOT.

Comment: I wasn't implying that an `inout` param creates "some persistent link", rather I was wondering if there was a good way to leverage pointers in Swift/ why `inout` has to being to be limited to the calling function. The patterns mentioned above are really helpful in any case.

Comment: See Jakes answer, where he references binding variables in SwiftUI. That sort of approach sounds like what you are answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't "link" a variable that way because `inout` only works in the scope it's declared.

If what you want is to have some kind of global state, you can wrap it in a class.

```
class Wrapper {
    var value = false
    init() {}
}

class Modifier {
    let wrapper: Wrapper
    init(wrapper: Wrapper) {
        self.wrapper = wrapper
    }
    
    func updateSwitch() {
        wrapper.value.toggle()
    }
}

let wrapper = Wrapper()
let modifier = Modifier(wrapper: wrapper)
modifier.updateSwitch()
print(wrapper.value) // this will read 'true'
```